# Python: Extract a certain string from the beginning of another string

Tags: python, dataframe

**current code:**

```py
    #defining what unwanted values can be in col instead of a date
    missing_date_values = ("None", "nan", "-inf", "NA", "Nan")

    for i, row in enumerate(data["col"]):
    #in case cell´s value starts with one of the tuple´s string values -> get 
    #length of that string and extract it into date column
    if row.startswith(missing_date_values):
        #LOOKING FOR THE CODE HERE
```

I created the tuple `missing_date_values` and now I am iterating over the column col of some dataframe. Whenever the cell´s value starts with one of the strings from the tuple I want to extract exactly this tuple´s string from the cell´s value. Therefore, I need a code that know with which of the tuple´s string values the cell starts. I am not allowed to use any packages.

I already managed to write a code that solves this issue but it looks unnecessarily lengthy.

**previous code:**

```py
    index = 0
    for value in data["col"]:
        if value.startswith("NA"):
            data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:2]
            data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][2:]

        elif value.startswith("-inf"):
            data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:4]
            data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][4:]

        elif value.startswith("NaN"):
            data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:3]
            data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][3:]

        elif value.startswith("nan"):
            data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:3]
            data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][3:]

        index += 1
```

Thank you for your help <3

PS.: New to the community

Comment: Please copy and paste your code, don't give us a screenshot.

Comment: I didnt understand this part "the tuple I want to extract exactly this tuple´s string from the cell´s value." can you please elaborate more on that.

Comment: e.g if the cell´s value is "NACherry Inc" the code should know that it starts with "NA" and not for example with "None" so it knows that it has to extract the length of "NA" so 2 characters from "NACherry Inc" in order to end up with "Cherry Inc". Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the shortest you are gonna get it:

```
missing_date_values = ("None", "nan", "-inf", "NA", "Nan")

for index, value in enumerate(data["col"]):
    for v in missing_date_values:
        if value.startswith(v):
            data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:len(v)]
            data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][len(v):]
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 0
for value in data["col"]:
  beg = [s for s in ("None", "nan", "-inf", "NA", "Nan") if value.startswith(s)]
  if beg:
    beg = beg[0]
    data["date"][index] = data["col"][index][:len(beg)]
    data["col"][index] = data["col"][index][len(beg):]

  index += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D

I am new to coding. Therefore, I gotta go with the other solution. Cannot fully wrap my head around list comprehensions yes :P